# How do I use SQLAlchemy, autoload, and Pyramid?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am trying to get SQLAlchemy to autoload my table columns (using MySQL, if that matters). I have:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base()    

class User(object):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'users', 'autoload': True}
```

Here is my error:

```
InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<class 'myproject.models.User'>'
```

I added an `__init__` function, and still get the same error:

```
def __init__(self,col1,col2):
    self.col1 = col1 
    self.col2 = col2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `User` class should have `Base` as its parent, not `object`:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
engine = create_engine(db_string, echo=db_echo)
Base = declarative_base()    
Base.metadata.bind = engine

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'users', 'autoload': True}
```

Comment: good catch. However, now I get a new error: sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: No engine is bound to this Table's MetaData. Pass an engine to the Table via autoload_with=<someengine>, or associate the MetaData with an engine via metadata.bind=<someengine>

Comment: Do I need the __init__(self,col1,col2) function? Sorry, still a newb to Python

Comment: No, you don't need a constructor, SQLAlchemy generates a default constructor for you which accepts all your column names as keyword parameters: `user = User(col1="blah", col2="foo")

Comment: Without the constructor I am getting an "Undefined variable from import: col1". I am using PyDev in Eclipse. (The app runs fine without the constructor)

Comment: Well, I guess that's an issue with PyDev and "magic" class attributes which are created by SA via autoload. It's up to you to decide whether you want to change (I'd say cripple) perfectly valid code to make PyDev happy... Maybe a better solution would be not to use autoload then and specify the columns manually.

Comment: Autoreflection is nice for quick prototyping, but in the long run it's a good idea to switch over to stop using it, and instead maintain a full definition of your database in python.  The latter technique lends itself very nicely to peforming semi-automated schema migrations using sqlalchemy's companion tool, Alembic, if and when you need to make a change to your database structure.  It also makes it easy to create a secondary database just for testing your application code.